# Odds of drawing specific 5 cards among 30

Tags: probability

We have 30 cards. We draw 15 of them.

1. What is the probability of drawing a specific combination of 5 cards, assuming all cards are unique?
2. What is the probability of drawing a specific combination of 5 cards, assuming there are 2 copies of each card?

(Additionally I'd love some pointers on where i can go to learn this kind of probabilistic math and how to do the calculations myself. Not sure what to search for to find this kind of information.)

Comment: By drawing a specific combination of $5$ cards, do you mean they have to be drawn in a specific order, or do they just have to be included in the $15$ that you take?

Comment: As a first lesson in probability theory try to formulate your questions in the context of probability theory

Comment: Order is not important, just the 5 cards in any order. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: You most likely need the [multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) and its generalizations.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not a mathematician, that math is way above my head. :)

Where can I go to get this question answered?